# Task vs Thread vs background worker for a lifetime method

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, backgroundworker

I'm little confused with all of this. I need to create a lifetime  method inside my application which it will Communicate with an asp net web service and it will returns me some results. As long my application is running, this method will never stop.

#### Method-1 creating an Task.

```
 t=Task.Run(()=>ffAsync());

 async void ffAsync()
 {
    while (true)
    {
      await Task.Delay(5000);
      Console.WriteLine("Reading from server every 5 seconds");
    }
 }
```

#### Method2 using background worker

```
Timer t = new Timer();   
t.Interval = 5000;    
timer1.Enabled = true;  
timer1.Tick += new 
System.EventHandler(OnTimerEvent);

private void OnTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Method-3 using Thread

```
new Thread(() =>
{
   Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
   while(true)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
      Console.WriteLine("Run every 5 seconds");
   }
 }).Start();
```

Which method is more effective in my case?
Also another optimization question, is it better to use a task.delay(x),Thread.Sleep(x) for running  my loop every x seconds, or creating a timer (as my seconds example) which it will trigger my event every x seconds?

Comment: Do you care about cancellability?  Do you care about managing exceptions from the main thread?  If you want work to go on in parallel "forever", you probably do not want to use up a thread-pool thread; to me it would make more sense to run on a thread that you create and let run.

Comment: Are you sure you need tokenSource in method 1? I don't think that you do. If this thread will run until your application dies, then you don't need it. Or am I missing something here? If I understand correctly, when all foreground threads are finished, then application will close and also, it will destroy any background threads. Next question: do you need result of this method? if you do, then you should use Task, if you don't, then Thread.

Comment: In some cases i will return some results from my method in ui thread. Example if server has some results i will open a new form to inform client what is this about. Which it will give me better performance and speed in my application?

Comment: Also which method is more prefered? Using a time or task.delay?

Comment: Keeping a thread around forever, mostly sleeping, it not normally a wise idea.  There is no fundamental difference between 1 and 2, Task.Delay also uses a Timer, you just can't see it.  Except for one nasty little detail, if what you actually do ever takes more than 5 seconds then BackgroundWorker will remind you about that with an exception.  The task just takes longer than 5 seconds, it already does now.

Comment: So task is the best option in my case? Also in backgroundworker i can use   if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy)

Comment: Never use `async void` (except for event handlers) – use `async Task` instead.

Comment: @ckuri: Though that is good advice in general, consider the specific case here.  What would you do with such a task?  It never completes normally, so awaiting it is probably the wrong thing to do unless you are awaiting it for the *exceptional completion*.  So what do you do with it?  The only thing to do with it would be exception handling, but that handling could be done *inside the loop itself*.

Comment: It depends. Many factors affect implementation, such as sync vs async calls, CPU or IO bound work and etc, so even while loop with sleep can be best option. I think you should go with easiest approach and tweak it with profiler to adjust for your case. Profiler and decompiler/IL viewer is best helpers when you seek performance.

Answer (score 4):

> Which method is more effective in my case?

None of these are right. All of them make background workers, which is wrong for IO bound tasks.

You would not hire a worker to do nothing but sleep 23 hours 59 minutes and 59.9999 seconds a day and do 0.0001 seconds of work.  So you should not hire a thread to do that either.

Asynchronous IO should be written to use asynchrony and should run on whatever context needs the result of the IO.  Do not use `Task.Run`. Use asynchronous IO inside the loop!

> is it better to use a `Task.Delay`, `Thread.Sleep` or creating a `Timer`?

Do not hire a worker and then make them sleep.  Either use a delay, or make a timer. Pick which ever one works better for your program structure. But the important thing is **all of the workflow should be done on the main thread and the IO calls must be asynchronous**.

Comment: If my main thread is a UI-thread (Winforms/WPF),  and I make it do "all the workflow", how will it have time to refresh the UI and allow for a responsive UI?

Comment: @joedotnot: By ensuring that (1) all waiting done for high latency IO operations is asynchronous, and (2) that every CPU computation performed takes less than, say, 30 milliseconds before it does an asynchronous yield of some sort. If you do that then the UI will be responsive faster than humans can perceive it and it will appear smooth.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but how do I provide an Asynchronous IO that returning a task without using a Task inside? I know there are built-in async methods. But do I need to go for native code to implement an asynchorny API?

Comment: @joe: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Maybe this will help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/asynchronous-file-i-o

Comment: @EricLippert Yes there are things like HttpClient.GetStringAsync from the framework runtime. But the question is how could we implement our own version of GetXXXXAsync without using built-in async API of .net runtime? The runtime doesn't cover everything. I can think of returning a Task.Run somewhere...took a glimpse at the implementation of GetStringAsync , seems to be pretty complicated. Is it hard create our own version without using .NET runtime library?

Comment: @joe: I'm not sure how to answer your question. It would be hard for me, that's for sure. I am really quite good at building semantic analyzers for programming languages and know pretty much nothing about implementation details of asynchronous IO. That's why I leave that job up to people who are experts at it.